# Why does Resharper give me an HTML Error "Unexpected token" here?

Tags: html, resharper

I get "Unexpected token" in this code:

```
@foreach (String day in daysOfMonth)
{
    <option id="selItem_@(day) value="day">@day</option>
}
```

...between the "y" and the """ (quotation mark) in:

```
value="day"
```

Why? Why is that token unexpected, and how should I assign the value in a manner acceptable to Resharper?

Comment: I think it must be because there should be a double quote after `<option id="selItem_@(day)`.

Comment: Now that you say that, it seems/looks obvious. Adding those (there were actually four of them) does do away with those messages, so that was the solution, if you want to make it an answer.

Comment: hey, i saw on your featured question that you were on 9990 and i couldn't help feeling sorry for you - so close to the 10k but not quite! that can be frustrating! So I gave you a couple of votes ;)

Comment: Thanks, Rachel - actually I've crossed that Rubicon several times. Whenever I get to around 10,050, I bountify one of my already-answered questions for 50 points. So you have moved someone a bit closer to getting an extra 50 points! I see you're from Ireland; my ancestors (on my dad's side) left Cork in 1820 for Canada. I don't know why they chose Canada, but they moved to California in the 1880s.

Comment: Canada's nice! Well so is cork, but employment wouldn't have been great in 1820! Cool tho, you can honestly say you're part Irish :) unlike so many, who are like 500 times removed!!!

Comment: I would like to go to Cork one day and visit the Rory Gallagher museum.

Comment: It's well worth it. It's a lovely city. But if you're gonna travel that far, stay a while and do a round trip. You can get from one end of Ireland to the other in a day or two, it's small! So visit a few places :)